# STM32 std peripheral library not building properly

Tags: arm, gdb, stm32

I am trying to make a simple LED blink program for stm32f334 nucleo board.
I am using GDB and OpenOCD  via stlink v2 to debug the program. The problem I have is that the LED is not blinking. When I try to break and step into any function (e.g. `GPIO_WriteBit` ), I hit the `g_pfnVectors`(I have checked it in disassembly).

My question is: 
Why the `g_pfnVectors` is called at the end of function call? Is this something that we expect ?

And why can't I step into the std peripheral lib functions?

```c
//Quick hack, approximately 1ms delay
void ms_delay(int ms)
{
    int j=0;
   for (int i =0;i<(ms);i++)
   {
       __asm("dsb");

   }
}


//Flash orange LED at about 1hz
int main(void)
{

    volatile uint8_t clock_src=255;
    //GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx =NULL; 
    GPIO_InitTypeDef  GPIO_InitStruct;
    RCC_HSICmd(ENABLE);
    RCC_SYSCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLKSource_HSI);
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);


     __asm("dsb"); 
//  GPIO_StructInit (&GPIO_InitStruct);
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin    =   GPIO_Pin_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode   =   GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType  =   GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed  =   GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd   =   GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&GPIO_InitStruct);

    for (;;) {
        GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_5,1);
        ms_delay(5000);
        GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_5, 0);
        ms_delay(5000);
              // Toggle the pin
    }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to forget about SPL as it is obsolete and not supported for many years not. It was replaced by the HAL libraries. I afraid that you have improperly configured toolchain as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I will look into the toolchain config  as well..